# How to concatenate two dictionaries to create a new one?

Tags: python, dictionary, concatenation

Say I have three dicts

```
d1={1:2,3:4}
d2={5:6,7:9}
d3={10:8,13:22}
```

How do I create a new `d4` that combines these three dictionaries? i.e.:

```
d4={1:2,3:4,5:6,7:9,10:8,13:22}
```

Comment: d4 = {**d1, **d2, **d3} --> {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 9, 10: 8, 13: 22}

Answer (score 360):

1. Slowest and doesn't work in Python3: concatenate the `items` and call `dict` on the resulting list:

   ```
   $ python -mtimeit -s'd1={1:2,3:4}; d2={5:6,7:9}; d3={10:8,13:22}' \
   'd4 = dict(d1.items() + d2.items() + d3.items())'

   100000 loops, best of 3: 4.93 usec per loop
   ```
2. Fastest: exploit the `dict` constructor to the hilt, then one `update`:

   ```
   $ python -mtimeit -s'd1={1:2,3:4}; d2={5:6,7:9}; d3={10:8,13:22}' \
   'd4 = dict(d1, **d2); d4.update(d3)'

   1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 usec per loop
   ```
3. Middling: a loop of `update` calls on an initially-empty dict:

   ```
   $ python -mtimeit -s'd1={1:2,3:4}; d2={5:6,7:9}; d3={10:8,13:22}' \
   'd4 = {}' 'for d in (d1, d2, d3): d4.update(d)'

   100000 loops, best of 3: 2.67 usec per loop
   ```
4. Or, equivalently, one copy-ctor and two updates:

   ```
   $ python -mtimeit -s'd1={1:2,3:4}; d2={5:6,7:9}; d3={10:8,13:22}' \
   'd4 = dict(d1)' 'for d in (d2, d3): d4.update(d)'

   100000 loops, best of 3: 2.65 usec per loop
   ```

I recommend approach (2), and I particularly recommend avoiding (1) (which also takes up O(N) extra auxiliary memory for the concatenated list of items temporary data structure).

Comment: I don't understand why `d4 = dict(d1, **dict(d2, **d3))` isn't faster than #2, but it isn't.

Comment: 1 above is best if working on small dicts as it is clearer in my opinion.

Comment: Just stumbled on this thread and I am consistently getting ~0.2 usec faster results using `d4 = d1.copy(); d4.update(d2, **d3)` than `d4 = dict(d1, **d2); d4.update(d3)`.  I know this is old but I thought I'd post my results.

Comment: Unless all keys are known to be strings, option 2 is an abuse of a Python 2 implementation detail (the fact that some builtins implemented in C bypassed the expected checks on keyword arguments). In Python 3 (and in PyPy), option 2 will fail with non-string keys.

Comment: If you discount the time penalty of importing `itertools` it appears that `dict(itertools.chain(d1.items(), d2.items(), d3.items()))` is a contender as well.

Comment: I would add that `d1.items() + d2.items()` doesn't works in Python 3.

Comment: Please update your answer, the first option won't work in Python3, which is what probably most people use by now.

Comment: This is very unreadable

Comment: What about dict comprehension? 

```d1={1:2,3:4}; d2={5:6,7:9}; d3={10:8,13:22}; d4={10:11,12:13}; d5={k:v for d in [d1,d2,d3,d4] for k,v in d.items()}```

Somehow I got:
```10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0371 usec per loop``` while having almost the same computation time as the one shown above (Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2)

Comment: @j_s dict comprehension works fastest for me as well, compared to the others listed in this answer, however, the looped dict update from another answer seems even faster: `d1={1:2,3:4}; d2={5:6,7:9}; d3={10:8,13:22}; d4={}; d4={ d4.update(d) for d in [d1,d2,d3]}`

Comment: In Python 3.5+ one can use the `**` notation: `d1={1:2,3:4}; d2={5:6,7:9}; d3={10:8,13:22}; d4 = {**d1, **d2, **d3}`, which for me was nearly 3x faster than #3 or #4 above (0.228 usec per loop vs. 0.661 or 0.595 usec for #3 or 4, respectively).  As mentioned above, #1 and #2 don't work on Python 3.

Comment: what a lie - #2 perfectly works on python3: 

>python --version
Python 3.6.4

>python -mtimeit -s'd1={1:2,3:4};d2={5:6,7:9};d3={10:8,13:22};d4=dict(d1,**d2);d4.update(d3)'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.011 usec per loop

Comment: There is really no use in cluttering the answer space with `%%timeit` operations, just answer the question.

Comment: Option 2) does not work in Python 3. All other options are slower and less obvious than the _obvious_ solution from the comment right below the answer – which is IMHO the best answer

Answer (score 202):

In python 2:

```
d4 = dict(d1.items() + d2.items() + d3.items())
```

In python 3 (and supposedly faster):

```
d4 = dict(d1)
d4.update(d2)
d4.update(d3)
```

The previous SO question that both of these answers came from is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-as-a-single-expression).

Comment: Instead of `d4 = dict(d1)` one could use `d4 = copy(d1)`.

Comment: @ds: That appears not to work. Perhaps you meant `from copy import copy; d4 = copy(d1)` or perhaps `d4 = d1.copy()`.

Comment: First version doesn't work on Python3.

Comment: Maybe `d4 = d1.copy()`

Comment: It does work in Python 3, but you have to cast the `dict_items` objects to real `list` objects. This is another case where Python 3 prioritised minor performance optimisations over simplicity and ease of use.

Answer (score 106):

You can use the [`update()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method to build a new dictionary containing all the items:

```
dall = {}
dall.update(d1)
dall.update(d2)
dall.update(d3)
```

Or, in a loop:

```
dall = {}
for d in [d1, d2, d3]:
  dall.update(d)
```

Comment: update does not build a new dictionary. It (as expected) updates the original one.

Comment: @A.J.Rouvoet: "The original one" in this case is a brand new empty dictionary in `dall`. This new dictionary gets repeatedly updated to contain all the elements. It's intentional that `dall` is changed.

Comment: Ah, my comment was purely on the way you phrased the first sentence. It suggested something that isn't the case. Although I admit a down vote may have been a bit harsh.

Comment: logically using update we can create new dictionary by updating other and if we do not need the previous dic we can delete them using del d1 in for loop .

Answer (score 51):

Here's a one-liner (`imports` don't count :) that can easily be generalized to concatenate N dictionaries:

#### Python 3

```
from itertools import chain
dict(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in (d1, d2, d3)))
```

and:

```
from itertools import chain
def dict_union(*args):
    return dict(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in args))
```

#### Python 2.6 & 2.7

```
from itertools import chain
dict(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in (d1, d2, d3))
```

Output:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> d1={1:2,3:4}
>>> d2={5:6,7:9}
>>> d3={10:8,13:22}
>>> dict(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in (d1, d2, d3)))
{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 9, 10: 8, 13: 22}
```

Generalized to concatenate N dicts:

```
from itertools import chain
def dict_union(*args):
    return dict(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in args))
```

I'm a little late to this party, I know, but I hope this helps someone.

Comment: `imports` *do* count. but the solution here is still interesting

Comment: for python 3.6 it should be `d.items()` instead of `d.iteritems()`. thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Just a detail for perfectionists, first version for Python3 is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @sandroscodelller Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: I don't understand why Python hasn't implemented "+" operator for this common dictionary concatenation.

Answer (score 34):

Use the dict constructor

```
d1={1:2,3:4}
d2={5:6,7:9}
d3={10:8,13:22}

d4 = reduce(lambda x,y: dict(x, **y), (d1, d2, d3))
```

As a function

```
from functools import partial
dict_merge = partial(reduce, lambda a,b: dict(a, **b))
```

The overhead of creating intermediate dictionaries can be eliminated by using the`dict.update()` method:

```
from functools import reduce
def update(d, other): d.update(other); return d
d4 = reduce(update, (d1, d2, d3), {})
```

Comment: Does not work in Python3 as the kwargs have to have string keys