# pass array of dictionaries to python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a bash script that builds a dictionary kind of structure for multiple iterations as shown below:

```
{ "a":"b", "c":"d", "e":"f"}
{ "a1":"b1", "c1":"d1", "e1":"f1", "g1":"h1" }
```

I have appended all of them to an array in shell script and they are to be fed as an input to python script and I want the above data to be parsed as list of dictionaries.

I tried some thing like this and it didn't work.

```
var=({ "a":"b", "c":"d", "e":"f"} { "a1":"b1", "c1":"d1", "e1":"f1", "g1":"h1" })

function plot_graph {
RESULT="$1"   python - <<END
from __future__ import print_function
import pygal
import os
import sys
def main():
    result = os.getenv('RESULT')
    print(result)
   if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
END
}
plot_graph ${var[@]}
```

Arguments are being split and they are not being treated as a single variable.

```
Out of result will be :[ {"a":"b", ]
```

where as I want the entire var value to be read as a string and then I can split it into multiple dictionaries.

Please help me get over this.

Comment: missing `,` on line 1

Comment: Tried adding that. Didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems problem of `plot_graph $var`

The following code should work:

```
var="({ 'a':'b', 'c':'d', 'e':'f'} { 'a1':'b1', 'c1':'d1', 'e1':'f1', 'g1':'h1' })"

echo $var



function plot_graph {
echo $1
RESULT="$1"   python - <<END
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
def main():
    result = os.getenv('RESULT')
    print(result)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
END
}
plot_graph "$var"
```

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the issue. I will try to form a var from array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want a concatenated dictionary with all keys. See [how to concatenate two dictionaries to create a new one in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781571/how-to-concatenate-two-dictionaries-to-create-a-new-one-in-python)