# Looking for a more pythonic way to merge a list full of dictionaries into one?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list with a bunch of dictionaries that I am trying to combine into one

Looks like this...

```
[{'name':'name', 'value':'john'}, {'name':'sex', 'value':'male'}, {'name':'color', 'value':'blue'}, {'name':'car', 'value':'toyota'}, {'name':'job', 'value':'cashier'}]
```

I'm trying to combine them all into one dictionary so that the name value is the key and the value is the value. Right now I'm doing something like this and it works fine but I know there is an easier way

```
keys = []
vals = []

for item in a:
    if item['name']:
        keys.append(item['name'])

    if item['value']:
        vals.append(item['value'])

md = dict(zip(keys,vals))
```

Any guidance would be appreciated... thank you

Comment: Perhaps, you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781571/how-to-concatenate-two-dictionaries-to-create-a-new-one-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension.

```
new = {i['name']:i['value'] for i in a}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your list of dictionaries is called dict_list you can use dict comprehension as below:

```
new_dict = { dict['name'] : dict['value'] for dict in dict_list}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to use the names of built-in classes as variable names (dict) in this case it should not matter but it is a bad habit

Comment: Good comment, I was just trying to make it blindingly obvious what object each step in the comprehension was trying to do (easy to get confused with abstractly named temp variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `dict.values()` for your specific case as keys and values are available in an order:

```
dict(d.values() for d in a)
```

Comment: Assuming that all the dictionaries have the name and value entries in the correct order

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this also.

```
input_dict_list = [{'name':'name', 'value':'john'}, {'name':'sex', 'value':'male'}, {'name':'color', 'value':'blue'}, {'name':'car', 'value':'toyota'}, {'name':'job', 'value':'cashier'}]

out_put_dict = {}
for input_dict in input_dict_list:
    out_put_dict[input_dict['name']] = input_dict['value']

print(out_put_dict)
```