# list (which contain a dict in it) inside dict to data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary-comprehension

Hi I have the following data

```
data = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4,
    "efgh": [
        {
            "e": 5,
            "f": 6,
            "g": 7,
            "h": 8
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to convert it to pandas data frame with the following format

[image]

I have tried with following method

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

Comment: You can first prepare the `data` dictionary as required by [extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277439/7283201) and [concatenating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1781571/7283201) items.

Comment: Updated my answer to a more correct and optimal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a bit like you are looking for [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)? If you do

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path="efgh", meta=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```

you'll get

```
   e  f  g  h  a  b  c  d
0  5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4
```

which is essentially what you want, just with the columns in a different order. You could adjust that by:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I'm actually looking for pd.json_normalize

Answer (score 0):

I create two dictionaries before key "efgh" and after.
I attach the dictionary "dict1" to the dictionary "dict2".
In pandas, we convert keys to columns, values to rows.

```
import pandas as pd

data = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "efgh": [ { "e": 5, "f": 6, "g": 7, "h": 8 } ] }
dict1 = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if k!="efgh"}
dict2 = {k: v for k, v in data['efgh'][0].items()}

dict1.update(dict2)

df = pd.DataFrame([dict1])

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is also helpful technique

Comment: Don't forget to vote for the answer (tick it below the upper and lower triangle).